# SQL case statement not executing else part

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

**Problem statement:**

Create a function to search a student with roll_no; if exists show "Student Name and Course" else show "Roll No not exist".

```
CREATE FUNCTION search(roll_num VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(150)
RETURN 
(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN `roll_no`= roll_num  THEN CONCAT (`student`.`student_name`,`student`.`course_id`)
        ELSE 'Roll No not exist '
        END
FROM `student`WHERE `student`.`roll_no` = roll_num);

SELECT search(31219005) ; //since this is an existing roll num everything went correct.
SELECT search(21219005) ; //this roll is not an existing one in the DB, but it simply shows NULL , instead of existing my else part.
```

Comment: ELSE part cannot be executed - WHERE gives zero output records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the wanted result, but i don't think that you wnat only the course id.

But this should help further

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION search(roll_num VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(150)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `student` WHERE `student`.`roll_no` = roll_num)) THEN
        RETURN (SELECT CONCAT (`student`.`student_name`,`student`.`course_id`) FROM `student`WHERE `student`.`roll_no` = roll_num);
    ELSE
        RETURN 'Roll No not exist ';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses....The problem is resolved and I have understood my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that when you don't find the roll_no, there is nothing (no row) to apply else to. One way to make sure that there is a row to return is to select from a constant table such as DUAL, or a values clause (but I think neither exists in MySQL) like:

```
select COALESCE(s.student_name, 'Roll No not exist')
from dual
left join students s
    on s.roll_num = ?
```

COALESCE will pick the first (from left) column that is not null. If a row exists, it will be chosen, if not the constant string.

Another variant is to use a union and add an ordering attribute as:

```
select t.student_name
from (
    select 0, student_name from student where roll_num = '1'
    union all
    select 1, 'Roll No not exist'
    order by 1
    limit 1
) as t;
```

Since we are picking the row with the lowest ordering number, an existing row will ha precedence over the constant row.

Since I believe that the function itself is not a problem, I'll leave it there